# How do I prove that this matrix exists?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

[image: This is the problem]

I have no idea how to solve this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are given an idea: "use the $QR$ facrotization of the matrix $S$".

Comment: Questions are expected to present more than simply a problem statement that you have found elsewhere.  A modest amount of context will help your Readers understand what you've tried and found to pose a difficulty, or simply why you think this problem is interesting.

Comment: You might want to look at schur triangular decomposition.

Comment: There's no merit to this problem beyond the fact that it's a homework problem, and we're not going to do your homework for you. Put in at least a modicum of effort.